# Is this code snippet not recommend or wrong, and why

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    const int N = 20;
    char* ptr0 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*N);
    *(char**)(ptr0) = ptr0; //is this line ok?
    free(ptr0);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm just wondering that, the 6-th line of code, `*(char**)(ptr0) = ptr0`, will that cause crash, or wrong result, thus not recommended write that, or it is just OK?

Comment: Yep, it's fine. The type-punning with `*(char**)` is not at violation of the strict-aliasing rule, because the pointer is of the same type and the pointer is type `char`. It's the same as `int a = 5; a = a;` (wonky, but fine) Note: your allocation is better as `char *ptr0 = malloc (sizeof ptr0 * N);` (you get storage for `N` pointers -- which is likely 8X more storage than you need -- but that's up to you) and See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Writing into malloc'd space is never a strict aliasing violation anyway

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I read your pasted related question & answers, make me aware that in pure C its not necessary to cast `void*` to `char*` for my pasted code. However, I've tested in both gcc 5.4 and Visual Studio 2017, for `test.c` as file name. VS2017 will report error, for default warning/error level setting. I would like write code that both gcc and Visual Studio can compile, thus I keep casting for malloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is 100% safe. Alignment is OK as the malloc result is always aligned. So you will just save the pointer at the beginning of the malloced memory.

It does not (IMO) break the strict aliasing rule as well

https://godbolt.org/z/p_8jrP

Comment: Wow, I like the website that you paste. Cool.